# Ajax invocation from Spring MVC Liferay 6.1 portal

Tags: ajax, liferay-6

We are using SpringMVC portlet framework with Liferay 6.1 for developing the portal. The current issue that we are facing is that we are not able to invoke the servResouce method in the controller class through the ajax calls from our jsp page.

Can anyone point to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring controller, define the resource method as

```
Public ModelAndView serveResource(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res)
{
  ...
  res.setContentType("application/json; charset=...");
  return new ModelAndView("res_page", model);
}
```

And setup your res_page.jsp response page, with:

```
<% page contentType="text/html; charset=..." %>
<%-- text/html has no effective effect on your response contentType --%>
<% (your taglibs) %>
{
  (your data)
}
```